# How do the shift and truncation functors affect hypercohomology groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

For $k$ a number field and $X$ a smooth geometrically integral variety, we denote by $\pi:X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} \, k$ the canonical morphism.

For the etale sheaf $\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$, we have a resolution
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{m,X} \rightarrow \mathcal{K}_X^* \rightarrow \mathcal{D}iv_X \rightarrow 0,$$
where $\mathcal{K}_X^*$ is the sheaf of invertible rational functions and $\mathcal{D}iv_X$ is the sheaf of Cartier divisors. Hence we get a canonical isomorphism
$$R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X} \cong R\pi_*[\mathcal{K}_X^* \rightarrow \mathcal{D}iv_X \rangle,$$
where $[\mathcal{K}_X^* \rightarrow \mathcal{D}iv_X \rangle$ is the co-cone of the morphism of complexes $\mathcal{K}_X^* \rightarrow \mathcal{D}iv_X.$

We have the following equalities
$$\mathrm{Pic}(X) = H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = H^1(k,R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = H^1(k,\tau_{\leq 1}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}),$$
$$\mathrm{Br}(X) = H^2(X,\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = H^2(k,R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = H^2(k,\tau_{\leq 2}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}).$$

In both cases, I can understand the second equality, since $\pi_*$ sends etale sheaves to discrete Galois modules, and so $R\pi_*$ does the same between their corresponding derived categories.

**Question 1.** How does one explain the third equality in both cases? It seems like truncation of the complex can preserve the hypercohomology, but it has to be by a correct integer $n$. Based on what I observe, $n$ has to coincide with the degree of the hypercohomology group. For example, in the case of $\mathrm{Br}(X)$, if we instead use the truncation functor $\tau_{\leq 1}$, then one gets
$$H^2(k,\tau_{\leq 1}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = \mathrm{Br}_1(X),$$
the algebraic Brauer group instead of the Brauer group.

Also, when applying Galois hypercohomology to the complex $R^2\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}[-2]$ shifted to the right by 2, one gets
$$H^1(k,R^2\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}[-2]) = 0,\,\,\, H^2(k,R^2\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}[-2]) = H^0(k,R^2\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}).$$

**Question 2.** My guess is that $H^p(k,R^n\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}[q]) \cong H^{p+q}(k,R^n\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X})$, but I can't justify it properly.

I'm not sure if the integer $n$ plays a role here. This certainly looks like some sort of spectral sequence. One comparison I can provide is that in the case of computing cohomology groups in a complex $K$, one obviously has
$$\mathcal{H}^p(K[q]) \cong \mathcal{H}^{p+q}(K).$$

Comment: Truncation keeps cohomology up to a certain degree and kills the rest.

Comment: @FernandoMuro In my example, $R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_m$ is a complex concentrated in degrees 0 and 1. So in some sense I guess if we replace $\tau_{\leq 2}$ by $\tau_{\leq n}$ for $n \geq 3$, we still have $H^2(k,\tau_{\leq n}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}) = \mathrm{Br}(X)$. This makes sense since we haven't actually changed anything except add more zeroes to the back. But interesting things can happen when our truncation changes some terms or kills some but not all of them as I mentioned.

Comment: Truncation doesn't change anything, it just keeps or kills. That is if we're talking about the standard t-structure, which I assume. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you are referring to the $i$-th cohomology group of a complex, in this case, it's either keep or kill as you said. But we're taking Galois cohomology with coefficients in the complex. So in my example, applying $H^2(k,-)$ to $\tau_{\leq 2}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$ is different from applying it to $\tau_{\leq 1}R\pi_*\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$. One gives us the Brauer group the other is the algebraic Brauer group. You can find this example in *Extended Picard complexes and linear algebraic groups* by Borovoi and van Hamel, section 2.18.

Comment: The trick is that the hypercohomology, i.e. derived global sections, preserves coconnective complexes (i.e. those concentrated in non-negative cohomological degree). Therefore you can see that truncation does not change the groups in dimension below the one being truncated.